# GZipping files on S3, compressend and uncompressed

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, compression

I am trying to gzip some of my larger .files and have taken the initial approach like here

[Can someone walk me through serving gzipped files from Cloudfront via S3 origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196236/can-someone-walk-me-through-serving-gzipped-files-from-cloudfront-via-s3-origin)

1. Gzip the file, remove the .gz and then set correct HTTP Headers.

Now this all works, but I am told some browsers won't support the gzip files, especially mobile.

So I want to do the approach where my folder contains both i.e.

```
myfile.js.gz &

myfile.js
```

And store them in my S3 Bucket, and cloudfront should as far as I am aware select the correct file based on which the browser can support ?

But if I have both in the folder, the larger myfile.js get selected each time.

Anyone know what I am missing here ?

Comment: Strongly advice to not serve files out of S3 directly due to cost and reaching S3 access limit (100req/sec) very soon. Try Nginx S3 proxy or CloudFlare which is essentially Nginx + CDN

Comment: @Anatoly [the limit is 800 GET requests/sec, 100 for PUT/DELETE/etc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html). But yes, CloudFront, CloudFlare, or MaxCDN are better options than treating S3 as a fast webserver. StevieB, show how you are requesting myfile.js.

Comment: @tedder42 exactly, S3 does its best as origin primary source

Comment: Cloudfront pulls our files from the S3 Bucket. But it looks like by default cloudfront is using the logic to select the right file out of the two it always just selects the uncompressed .js file

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use JavaScript necessarily? Not sure about the Cloudfront part but for gzipping, you can also use a Python Lambda function. With the `gzip`and `zipfile` libraries, it could be pretty easy:

```
            with zipped.open(file, "r") as f_in:
                gzipped_content = gzip.compress(f_in.read())
                destinationbucket.upload_fileobj(io.BytesIO(gzipped_content),
                                                        final_file_path,
                                                        ExtraArgs={"ContentType": "text/plain"}
                                                )
```

There's a full tutorial for the lambda function here: https://medium.com/p/f7bccf0099c9